# Use multiple zfs pools in LXD

Tags: zfs, lxd

I have several pools: tank1, tank2 and tank3.

How can I make LXD container use designated pool. eg. C1 & C2 use tank1, C3 use tank2, C4 & C5 use tank3?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it at the moment you init the container:

```
lxc init <image> <name> -s <pool>
```

I you have already created you containers in other pool, you need to stop them, publish as images, delete original containers and init them in new storage pool:

```
lcx stop c1
lxc lxc publish -f c1 --alias c1
lxc delete c1
lxc init c1 c1 -s <new pool>
lxc start c1
lxc image delete c1
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, each lxd host can only use one pool.